# Trying to saveChanges() in Oracle DB using .Net Core 3.1 and Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore v3.19

Tags: oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I've been trying to take advantage of Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore v3.19 provider for .NetCore.

I've followed Oracle's tutorial in terms of testing these features together.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/EFCoreSampleCode.html#GUID-71B4A0A3-7B88-4D4D-BC99-8ACB2F344280

My code is exactly as one the above.

I've also created Blog and Post tables in my Database schema.

But everytime i run it get an Exception (at the db.SaveChanges(); line):

OracleException: ORA-06550: line 13, column 14:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 13, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Please let me know if there's something i can try to move on from this.

Comment: How **exactly** did you name your tables? Did you, by any chance, enclose their names into double quotes and used mixed case? If so, then you have to do it always, everywhere - enclose them into double quotes and match letter case exactly as you used it while creating those tables.

Comment: I've used Oracle Sql Developer to create them, and when i open the Tables Tab, it shows me 'BLOG' and 'POST' tables. with Caps.

Comment: That looks OK, so - it's not the problem. I wouldn't know why Oracle complains that table doesn't exist, sorry.

Comment: I've found in a couple forums that we might need to add some quotes when we're using raw queries. 
But my problem is I'm not even naming the tables I want to insert into. 
I've followed the tutorials which lead me to believe this was possible:
public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
var blog = new Blog {URL = "https://blogs.oracle.com" };
context.Blogs.Add(blog);
context.SaveChanges();

But by some reason, this is not working at all.

Comment: @TiagoSilva, Oracle throws this exception when 1) You do not have privileges 2) You have defined wrong schema name.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv inside my DbContext class I added the method:

OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
                modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("SMITH");
}

Where I define the schema (I've checked in Oracle SQL Developer and 'SMITH' is the schema where I placed the tables). 
I thought this would guarantee I'm querying in the proper schema, but it seems not to be the case.

Comment: @TiagoSilva, enable logging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/ and check what has been sent to Oracle. Also verify permissions.

Comment: Hi @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks for the input. It definitely seems like Logging is the way to go since I've checked my permissions and I had already granted select, create, delete permissions for this "SMITH" user. 

Unfortunately it seems like DbContextOptionsBuilder does not contain a definition for 'LogTo' nor do I seem to be able to create a ILoggerFactory to use on top of my DbContextOptionsBuilder. 

It seems like it is not supported for .net Core 3.1 or that method is available through a provider that's incompatible with Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore v3.19.
Thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually related to the ServiceName I was using in my connection. By default it should "XE".
Somewhere throughout the installation this image was shown, leading me to believe that my serviceName would be 'XEPDB1'

[Oracle Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVnpb.png)

Once I started using the "default" ServiceName 'XE', everything started to work smoothly.
Given that I was still using modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("SMITH"); in context Class.

Thanks for all the help guys.